# Why should my small .NET development company upgrade from Team Foundation Server 2008 to 2010?

Tags: .net, tfs

The company for which I work has an MSDN site license and upgrading to TFS 2010 from 2008 is not an  expensive option.  However, neither my colleagues nor I have been able to find any features that make this something we feel we *need*.  Is anyone experienced with TFS 2010 enough to convince me that my company needs this?

**To clarify**: we have no intention of moving to a different source control product. The question is what features of TFS 2010 are worth an upgrade from TFS 2008?

Comment: I own some Microsoft stock and would really appreciate it if you did?

Comment: do not vote to close! the question is very interesting!

Comment: On a more serious note, have you watched this (somewhat dated) PDC presentation http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL52/?

Comment: The only thing from TFS I am missing is the ability to run MS Test Manager. Other than that, I also see very little reason to buy it. But I'm also interested in the replies to this question.

Comment: Talk to the Jedi. If he tells you you need it, resistance is futile ;-)

Comment: The question is not about TFS vs something else, its about going from TFS2008 to 2010 and is therefore a valid question.

Comment: Voted to reopen.  This question is completely legitimate and the answers will provide insight to many companies in the same situation currently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*disclaimer:  I haven't moved to 2010 yet either, but probably will*

Biggest feature for me:
(we use branching to manage large feature sets and to separate SPs, QFE's, and major releases)

TFS 2010 will track changes across branches.
Example:  suppose I change something in the Dev branch, and then you merge dev to main.  Now suppose that someone uses the Annotate feature (on the main branch) to figure out who changed that code.  In TFS 2008, it would report that you made the change (because you checked in the merge).  Reportedly, TFS 2010 will be aware that I actually orginated the change in the dev branch, and it will be able to tell you that.  That's gold if you are using branching.

Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but didn't they switch 2010 to use a single SQL database? (or maybe 1 for source control, and one warehouse?).  If so, then the backup strategy gets a bit better.  MS says that all of the TFS databases should be backed up from the same moment in time, but that's tough to do when there are 5-odd databases (it's very difficult to ensure that all of them reflect exactly the same point in time transactionally).  If they have consolidated databases, then it should be easier.

One other:  depending upon the level of MSDN that you have, TFS 2010 might be free for you now.

Comment: my team creates new features branches frequently, and this has always been an annoyance with TFS 2008. good answer

Answer (score 2):

If it costs you money to do so, I couldn't provide you with a great reason why you should upgrade.  If it were a free upgrade, I would do it simply to stay current.

Answer (score 2):

My number one reason for moving to tfs 2010 was our move from VS 2008 to 2010.  Quite frankly I just didn't want to deal with *ANY* issues in using a newer product (studio) with an older one (tfs).

To be fair, I don't personally know of incompatibilities, but my time is precious enough that I certainly don't want to find myself in a position where I have to upgrade my server later (probably at a critical juncture) because something isn't working right.

BTW, when I first read the "upgrade" path instructions, it was a little scary.

Step 1. Backup everything ( good ).
Step 2. Uninstall everything.. ( scary part )
Step 3. Install the new TFS
Step 4. finally get to do the actual upgrading of the databases.

Step 2 is what I almost turned back on.  the idea of spending an unknown amount of time  restoring the TFS server from backup was not a pleasant one.  However, in the end, the upgrade process was absolutely smooth.  With the longest amount of time uninstalling visual studio 2008 (required for the build server and various testing pieces).  That took a couple hours.

So far I haven't really used any of the "new" features yet.  The upgrade let our existing build scripts to continue doing deployments; which is one of the features I'm looking forward to playing with when I have time.

Comment: I'm so happy to hear from someone who actually went through the upgrade.  Thanks for this valuable information.

Comment: BTW, even though my upgrade process went smooth I would recommend that you bring up the new TFS server in parallel to the existing one with the idea of retiring the existing server as soon as the new one is up.  Also, I've noticed that 2010 takes a bit more resources than 2008 did on the server side.  Not sure if that matters.

Comment: Your backup strategy for your server can help to make life easier for you as well.
In addition to regular SQL Server backups, we take image backups of the app server.  With an image back up of the app server, if you need to recover (from a disaster, or step 2), you just restore the SQL Server databases, and restore the app server from image backup and you are back in business.

Answer (score -1):

We looked at TFS - but the management headaches were simply too much. We then went with a combo of SVN,  Jira and fisheye.

We did evaluate the TFS quite extensively, but frankly at the 2008 release point, we didn't find anything that'd have compelled us to move. But then your millage might vary.

Comment: I don't see how this answer is about vs 2008 vs. vs 2010

Comment: Management of TFS is actually quite simple, if you read the documentation.  Set up security groups in AD for the different types of users you want and map those groups to the built-in TFS roles.  With 2010, configuration and setup is very streamlined.  It takes longer to install the prerequisites than it does to install and configure TFS, in my experience.

Answer (score -2):

In general using a bunch of opensource projects, and free versions of team city, svn, ankh, etc. You can get what TFS has to offer for free, or almost at no costs, so perhaps the only reason is that you will get all of this in one package, integrated with visual studio which is a good and a bad thing.

the bad thing is that the company I worked for had tfs and my workspace mapping blew up 3 times in a year, now this may sound like no big deal in a years time, but downloading the whole tree was a 4-5 hours of pain and frustration.

the up side of tfs is the shelve feature, I use it constantly.

Comment: We aren't planning on using a different source control product than TFS.  The question what features of TFS 2010 warrant an upgrade from TFS 2008 (the version we are currently using).

Comment: I don't see how this answer is about vs 2008 vs. vs 2010

Comment: FWIW:  The difference to me was service.  I've used 5 or 6 different source control tools professionally, and at one point or another, every one of them went down.  We had a TFS (2005) outage once, and MS support was fantastic.  They helped us to get up and running again, and to identify and repair the orphaned record issue that caused the problem -- all within a day of the incident.  Maybe I've just been unlucky, but I've never had nearly as good an experience when an open-source system goes down.

Comment: If you think you can get what TFS has to offer for free, you are not using it right.  TFS != version control.  None of the products you mention are ALM.